# Nested trigger exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception, triggers, nested

Currently, I have a trigger that allows a field to be null or empty, but I add it to my table and it throws an error:

> SQL Error [217] [S0001]: Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

I put both of the triggers in the code below. The `_company` trigger works, but the `_proposal` trigger doesn't.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.DONOTUPDATE_company
ON company
AFTER UPDATE
AS  
    UPDATE company
    SET company.nr_lastbuc = deleted.nr_lastbuc
    FROM company
    INNER JOIN deleted ON company.nr_enlacecontract = deleted.nr_enlacecontract
    WHERE ((LEN(company.nr_lastbuc) = 0 OR company.nr_lastbuc IS NULL) 
           AND LEN(deleted.nr_lastbuc) > 0)
```

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.DONOTUPDATE_proposal
ON proposal
AFTER UPDATE
AS  
    UPDATE proposal
    SET proposal.ob_channel = deleted.ob_channel
    FROM proposal
    INNER JOIN deleted ON proposal.id_proposal = deleted.id_proposal
    WHERE ((LEN(proposal.ob_channel) = 0 OR proposal.ob_channel IS NULL) 
            AND LEN(deleted.ob_channel) > 0)
```

I am out of ideas. Suggestions?

Comment: What is the point of these triggers? The only thing they appear to be attempting to accomplish is making a column so it can't be updated under certain conditions. You should look into INSTEAD OF triggers if that is what you are trying to accomplish. Or better yet, fix your update procedure so it skips those columns.

Comment: If you do a self update in a trigger you will cause infinite recursion unless you add a condition to prevent the trigger from updating on the second run through. Very tricky area...

Comment: the point of these triggers its to avoid that a value on nr_lastbuc be null or be empty because several web services (WS) write on that column and they save the current state of the row,example ,  WS1 has a state (nr_enlacecontract, nr_lastbuc)=(1,1) and WS2 has state(nr_enlacecontract, nr_lastbuc)=(1,null) so depending which one writes first we keep the last info that was writed, the trigger of company keeps the last info that was not null or had length greater than 0 and doesn't let the field to be null or blank